# How to join two columns without repeating the FROM/WHERE clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have two tables `Contracts` and `ServiceProviders`. A contract has a property `LeadServiceProvider` which references a service provider.

I also have a third table called `SubServiceProviders` that maintains a many-to-many relationship between `Contracts` and `ServiceProviders` acting as sub service providers.

I'd like to run a query on Contract that would give me a list of all service providers - Lead and Sub, together in one column:

```
Select 
    c.LeadServiceProvider, subSP.ServiceProvider
From 
    Contracts c 
left join 
    SubServiceProviders subSP on c.ID = subSP.Contract
Where 
    [Some contract criteria goes here]
```

The query above gives me two columns that ideally I would like to flatten into one and run a `distinct()` on. I could do a select for `LeadServiceProvider` and then `UNION` it with a select for `SubServiceProviders`.

That is simple enough for this example, but, in my actual application, the `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses are pretty complicated, and if I'm to use `UNION`, I'm forced to repeat those clauses all over again

Comment: you could union both Lead and Sub before joining. Performance wise however, it's probably best to go with your first thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you could use CROSS APPLY here:

```
Select distinct
    v.ServiceProvider
From 
    Contracts c 
left join 
    SubServiceProviders subSP on c.ID = subSP.Contract
cross apply
    (values (c.LeadServiceProvider), (subSP.ServiceProvider)) as v (ServiceProvider)
Where 
    [Some contract criteria goes here]
```

[CROSS APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) is supported in SQL Server 2005 and later versions, the [VALUES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) row constructor in SQL Server 2008 and later. You can replace the VALUES clause with an equivalent UNION ALL subquery to make the query compatible with SQL Server 2005:

```
(
select c.LeadServiceProvider
union all
select subSP.ServiceProvider
) as v (ServiceProvider)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a simple'ish way to do this in one query, you can use a CTE and unpivot the columns.  I would do this explicitly with a `join` like this:

```
with t as (
      Select c.LeadServiceProvider, subSP.ServiceProvider
      From Contracts c left join SubServiceProviders subSP on c.ID = subSP.Contract
      Where [Some contract criteria goes here]
     )
select distinct (case when n.n = 1 then LeadServiceProvider else ServiceProvider end) as SP
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2) n;
```

EDIT:

You can just as easily put this in a subquery:

```
select distinct (case when n.n = 1 then LeadServiceProvider else ServiceProvider end) as SP
from (<your query here without the order by>) t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2) n;
```

Or forget the subquery:

```
  Select distinct (case when n.n = 1 then c.LeadServiceProvider
                        else subSP.ServiceProvider
                   end)
  From Contracts c left join
       SubServiceProviders subSP
       on c.ID = subSP.Contract cross join
       (select 1 as n union all select 2) n
  Where [Some contract criteria goes here]
```

Comment: Nice! Unfortunately, this won't work since the framework I'm using will blindly paste in this query into a larger query, so CTE's aren't an option

Comment: @NikIvanov . . . You can just put it in a subquery instead of a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

```
The query above gives me two colums that, ideally, I would flatten into
 one and run a distinct() on
```

If I am understanding you correctly... why not do something like this. You need the above query to be distinct...

```
Select DISTINCT * from (
Select c.LeadServiceProvider, subSP.ServiceProvider
From Contracts c left join SubServiceProviders subSP on c.ID = subSP.Contract
Where [Some contract criteria goes here]) aliasname
```

That would give you the above query but only distinct items.
*Note: Not run through any editor yet so I havent validated syntax*

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle SQL you can always use a normal with command to eliminate the need for multiple times use of the same table and then join them together

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
select distinct id, ServiceProvider from (
(Select distinct
    id, LeadServiceProvider as ServiceProvider, 1 as isLead, otherWhereCriteria
From 
    Contracts  ) l
union all
(Select distinct
    Contract, ServiceProvider, 0 as isLead, otherWhereCriteria
From 
    Contracts c inner join 
    SubServiceProviders s on c.ID = s.Contract) s
) u
Where
    otherWhereCriteria = targetValues
```

Comment: That's what I meant by saying "I could do a select for LeadServiceProvider and then UNION it with a select for SubServiceProviders" - I don't want to repeat the FROM clause (though your way does avoid repeating the WHERE clause), primarily because the actual query has 7 inner joins

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an ideal time to use `unpivot`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT subpvt.serviceprovider
FROM   (SELECT c.leadserviceprovider, subsp.serviceprovider, c.id
        FROM   contracts c
               LEFT JOIN subserviceproviders subsp ON c.id = subsp.contract
        WHERE  /*Some contract criteria goes here*/
                    ) p UNPIVOT (id
                        FOR serviceprovider
                        IN (leadserviceprovider, serviceprovider)) subpvt
```

Caveat: This is untested as the Op did not provide sample data and I can't be bothered to fabricate any.